# Sparse Data in Linear Model with Interaction: How to exclude when NA´s exeed threshold?

Tags: r, regression, subset, sparse-matrix, na

[Here's](https://fastupload.io/en/ZSfUBQAWD0sjbVy/file) a link to a small sample of my data as a csv.

I have a dataframe called data_pheno where I have a set of defined columns to be used independent variables and another set of dependent variables. I need to create and save a linear model for all possible combinations of independent and dependent variables. More so, I need to run these models with an interaction with another column called "species" (this time unchanging for every model). I do this by running two nested for loops like this:

```
var_independent <- c(7,8)
var_dependent <- c(5,6)

all_models <- list()

for (i in var_independent) {
  for (j in var_dependent) {
    lm <- lm(data_pheno[[j]] ~ data_pheno[[i]] * data_pheno_species
    
    #add names for models
    name <- paste(names(data_pheno)[j], "_vs_", names(data_pheno)[i],sep = "")
    # Store the model in the named list
    all_models[[name]] <- lm
    }  
}
```

This works perfectly as intended. The issue I have though is with the interaction term in the "species" column. In data_pheno multiple different species of plants have datapoints collected over multiple years. There will be about 10 rows for every species in data_pheno. The resulting linear models will include one coefficient for the i-th column, one for each destinct species in the column "species" and one interaction-coefficient for every species against the variable i.

The issue comes when for a particular combination of columns i and j there are only 2 to 3 complete cases for a certain species. This leads to a bad model which leads to further problems later on.

How could I exclude some specific species if it has less than 3 complete cases to be used in the linear model?
In my example data you can see that there are only 2 values present in the SFD column for the species " Rh. canadense 1990.0430A". This species should therefore be excluded from all models that are run with the SFD column.

The var_dependent and var_independent vectors in the code above are already updated to fit this sample.

Comment: The tags should indicate what computer language, and modules/packages you are using,  Those are more important than generic terms like 'subset' or 'na'..

Comment: Duh. Thank you, long post and forgot the most important thing.